# Sharepoint Rest API - Updating a column of a list inside a Page

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Page inside SitePages that contains a list. I can access the page with (GET) /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(29)

However, on the above GET response, the list does not show up, how I access a list that is inside a Page?

I also need to update a column value of all rows inside that list, is that possible?

Thanks in advance!
Sérgio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list inside the page, directly use the List Title with Rest API like this:

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitleInsidePage')/items

As /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(29) will return the metedata column for Site Pages but not the list inside page.

And if you want to update the list column inside the page, still directly use the ListTitle inside page:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name Inside Page')/items(Your record ID)",  
    type: "POST",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "IF-MATCH": "*",  
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"  
    },  
    data: "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.YourlistnameListItem'},Title:"  
    Ur new input "}",  
    /*where Title is column name and add your desired new data*/  
    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data.d.results);  
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
});
```

And if you need to update all rows, replace with item Id in the request above, it's not available to update all rows in one time using Rest API.